# how to disable button when date(d-m-Y) value is less than date(30-m-Y) using if condition PHP

Tags: php, date, if-statement, button, html-table

i have workers or employee table .. and i have Resign Date  inside the table ..

and there is Edit Button, Replace Button and Delete button in every single data in table ..

Replace BUTTON is for replacing the new worker over the resigned worker.. and i already make the button disable when the resign date is empty and enable when it not empty .

**now i don't know how can i make the button enable in next month of resign date.**

for example :
if somebody resigns on 17/3/2021, the button should be disabled until 1/4/2021 (the first day of the next month) .. i hope someone can help me

here is my table :

```
   $data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
        $kode=trim($data ['id_mcm']);
        $kode_mcm=trim($data ['kode_mcm']);
        $nama_mcm=trim($data ['nama_mcm']);
        $kode_ctr=trim($data ['kode_ctr']);
        $nama_ctr=trim($data ['nama_ctr']);
        $no_ktp=trim($data ['no_ktp']);
        $no_hp=trim($data['no_hp']);
        $domisili=trim($data['domisili']);
        $tgl_join=date_format($data ['tgl_join'],'d-m-Y');
        
if ($data ['tgl_resign']!=''){$tgl_resign=date_format($data ['tgl_resign'],'d-m-Y'); 

<!--i tried to added this code below so i can use if inside Replace button tag with less operation-->
$tgl_resign_baru=date_format($data ['tgl_resign'],'30-m-Y');
    
 }else{$tgl_resign='';}
        
        $alamat=trim($data['alamat']);
         ?>
        <tr <?php if($tgl_resign!=''){echo 'style="background-color:#f2c4cd"';} else {echo'';}?>>
        <td><?php echo ++$no_urut;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $kode_mcm;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $nama_mcm;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $kode_ctr;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $nama_ctr;;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $no_ktp;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $no_hp;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $domisili;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $tgl_join;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $tgl_resign;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $alamat;?></td>
      <td>
```

**and here is the Button tag :**

```
<!-- button Modal  replace-->       
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myy<?php echo $kode; ?>" 
<?php if (($akses=="Leader" || $akses=="IT") && $tgl_resign!="" && $kode_mcm!="" 
 && $tgl_resign>$tgl_resign_baru) <-- and i add this too . but it doesn't work 
{ 
 echo '';
}else{
    echo 'disabled';}?>>
    Baru
</button>
```

Comment: To clarify, if somebody resigns on _17/3/2021_, the button should be disabled until _1/4/2021_ (the first day of the next month)? You list _1/3/2021_ in your question, which doesn't seem to make sense. You should be using `t` to determine the last day of the month instead of assuming 30 (https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php). And your date format should be `YYYY-MM-DD`. Then you can use [date_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) to determine if the resign date (formatted `Y-m-t` = `2021-03-31` with your given example) is less than your compared month.

Comment: oh sorry i already edited the question .. and thanks for ur reply n i will try it now n see what gonna happen .. thnx again for ur reply @WOUNDEDStevenJones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this logic by setting the resign date to the the end of the month, and then comparing that to the current date. If it's greater than or equal to the current date you can disable the button.

```
<?php

$resignDate = '2021-03-17';
$resignDateEOM = date('Y-m-t', strtotime($resignDate)); //2021-03-31

$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');

if ($resignDateEOM >= $currentDate) {
    echo 'resign date end-of-month is still in the future';
}
```

```
<?php
    $disabled = '';
    if (
        ($akses=="Leader" || $akses=="IT")
        && $tgl_resign!=""
        && $kode_mcm!="" 
        && $resignDateEOM >= $currentDate
    ) {
        $disabled = 'disabled';
    }
?>
<button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-success btn-xs"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#myy<?= $kode; ?>"
    <?= $disabled; ?>
></button>
```

Comment: it's Work brother .. thanks a lot for ur help brother .. :) ,,i votedup ur answer but my reputation is still less than 15 .. and thank u soo much again brother . :)